# Using regular expression in Word merge condition

Tags: regex, ms-word, mailmerge

Having trouble getting a condition to match when creating a Word mail merge. What I want is to match based on the first letter of the field. If the first letter is K-Z, then it should evaluate True.

I have the following in Word:

{ IF { MERGEFIELD Provider } = "[K-Z]*" "Person1" "Person2" }

which does not work. I've tried escaping the square brackets, but this also has had no success.

I can't find anything useful on a search. Has anyone got any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: I'm not sure how regexes are used in Word, but for a word to be in format [K-Z][something], the proper regex to match against the word would be `[K-Z]+*`. Or, if you also want to accept chars only (e. g. L, N, Q, Y), `[K-Z].*`

Comment: Can VBA functions be called from Word merge fields, similar to the way Excel formulas or Access SQL statements can call VBA functions? Then you could use the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions library.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use regex expressions in Word IF fields - not even the limited regex that you can use in Word's Find and Replace function. In an IF field, all you get is the wildcards ? (to match any character) and * (to match multiple characters). Even these have their limitations.

So you have to find another way. One is the tedious one where you enumerate all the possibilities - in this case you could use something like

```
{ SET KtoZ 0 
}{ IF "{ MERGEFIELD Provider }" = "K*" "{ SET KtoZ 1}" 
}{ IF "{ MERGEFIELD Provider }" = "L*" "{ SET KtoZ 1}"
}{...
}{ IF "{ MERGEFIELD Provider }" = "Z*" "{ SET KtoZ 1}"
}{IF { REF KtoZ } = 1 "Person1" "Person2" }
```

(with similar IF fields for M..Y where I have put "..."). If you need to deal with upper/lower case you can add a suitable switch to your MERGEFIELD fields to.

Another way, depending on your situation and on the data source, might be to do the comparison in the data source. That requires either that you can create a view (or in Access, a query) that performs the comparison and returns, for example, a field called KtoZ, or that you can construct your query in SQL and issue it in a Word VBA OpenDataSource call. In the latter case, your data source must use a SQL dialect that lets you do that, and your query must be less than the 255/511 character limit that Word VA imposes.

Comment: I was hoping I could get away with not having to make the nested IFs but if that's the only way to do it., I guess I'll have to bite the bullet. Thanks.

Comment: I would avoid nested IFs, because they only nest 20 deep or some such, so e.g. extending the test to "D to Z" would probably require a rethink anyway. Generally better to use a construct along the lines of the one I have provided and avoid nesting.